# Draw line between 2 CGPoint without using to many addLine

Tags: swift, path, swiftui, shapes

I'am trying in SwiftUI to draw a line between to `CGPoint(x:0, y:0)`, `CGPoint(x:100, y:100)`

```
struct Line : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 100))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 0))
        return path
    }
}
```

```
struct GpsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Line()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)   
    }
}
```

Is there any way around easiest instead to specify 4 `CGPoint`, something where I can just say from point 1 to point 2? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Why **do** you need to specify 4 points, rather than the 2 you want?

Comment: me either, I have tried to specify only 2 point , path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)) and path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)) and I don't see anything on the screen.. my be I forget some modifier..I can't find the reason...

Answer (score 3):

Use `stroke` and `fill` property.

```
struct Line : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
        return path
    }
}
struct GpsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Line()
            .stroke(lineWidth: 5.0)
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have forgotten to `stroke` your line. `fill`ing the line fills the region enclosed by the line, which is why you always need 4 points.

You just need 2 points:

```
struct Line : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
        return path
    }
}
```

Usage (this is where you `stroke`):

```
Line()
    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
```